# How to Update Path Value Dynamically

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

As Path is not a dependency property, we wont be able to bind a value to it at runtime.

Then what is the MVVM alternate?

I want to achieve something like below without writing code behind:

```
<Binding  Source="{StaticResource LocalDictionaryValues}" Path="{Binding Resource.Columns}"/>
```

Comment: o.O Why would you update Path? You should rather update value in the binding source.

Comment: Sounds like your design is not the best. In MVVM the view should interpret the state of the VMs bound to it. To have a logic which changes the path of a `Binding` is definitely breaking the pattern. So what do want to achieve?

Comment: @DHN I am trying to get the values from Resex File. The resex file value may change when localization happens

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix Reason mentioned on above comment

Comment: @Simsons But the structure of a resex file stays the same, at least if you're using the standard ways of doing it. What changes is the `Source`. So you could have a VM which is delivering the right resex dictionary.